# Adding graphics to TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm making a little visualization based on a `TreeView`, but with some colorful graphics to show extra information.

I have a class which extends `TreeView`. I've added the control to a form and populated it with the nodes.

Now what I would like to do is to add some graphics to it. I would like to add a fixed width (say, 100px-wide, and the height of the text) graphic to the *left* of the text, but the *right* of the vertical indentation line.

How do I:

1. Move the text over to the right by 100px to make room for the graphic, and
2. Add the graphic at that particular location?

It is tempting to simply add spaces before the text, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Let's say I can always fall back on spacing the text if I can't find a better solution, I still need a way to determine the X,Y co-ordinates for where to place the graphic.

Thank you.

(I'm using C#2.0 with WinForms)

Comment: That's not possible, the native control doesn't support a background image and its ownerdraw is limited to nodes.  You'll need to start thinking about WPF if features like these are important to you.

Comment: Doesn't Treeview already support images? I use treeview with images in my IM program.

Comment: As Hans Passant mentioned, you can do this easily in WPF by writing a hierarchical data template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this control has the two features you require (if not can you post a mock up  screenshot): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13999/Using-treenodes-with-and-without-images-in-a-TreeV

Comment: This isn't really practical - I need much wider images.

Comment: cool well at least you hadn't seen it before, have you done any research? I'm not sure what Ozzah is saying about 16x16, afaik you can have bigger images:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/22624d65-fc70-4cd6-a725-c6b2332d1222

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, you're right. I just gave it a try - It is certainly possible to specify the dimensions of the image, and @user1002358 all you need to do is `TreeView.ImageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 16);`